# Webpack - can it automatically compile the bundled file upon code changes?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Sometimes I forget to run `npm run build` before pushing my code to production. If the bundle.js file could be built automatically in the background upon code changes, it could deal with that.

Is this possible?

If so, what do you think is the best way to do it?

I'm using `webpack-dev-server` during development.

Comment: you should look into using some CI/CD process which would run that command `npm run build` for you every time you pushed new work to your master branch

Comment: CircleCI, github actions, etc

Comment: @maxwell, would you mind sharing why you think this should be done on the server side? Currently I'm looking to do this on the client side as I don't even have node installed on the server side, among other reasons